# angular2.0.0-rc4：when I jumped the route,the page loading is slowly

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

When I jump routing(all of the routing), page loading slowly, need 6 to 10 seconds.Usually I have to click the route twice, page was able to fully display. I couldn't find why this phenomenon.

I'm using "@angular/router": "3.0.0-beta.2".

main.routes.ts:

```
{path: '', redirectTo: '/static/real_time_results', pathMatch: 'full'},
{path: 'static/setting', component: Setting,children:[
    {path: '', redirectTo: 'date', pathMatch: 'full'},
    {path: 'network', component: SettingNetwork},
    {path: 'date', component: SettingTimeAndDate},
    {path: 'video', component: SettingVideo}
]},
{path: 'static/deployment', component: Deployment},
{path: 'static/real_time_results', component: RealTimeResults}
```

seed-app.html:

```
<ul class="nav nav-sidebar">
                <li *ngFor="let menu of menus" [routerLinkActive]="['active']" [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{ exact: false }">
                    <a class="row nav-list" [routerLink]="menu.address">
                        <div class="col-xs-8">
                            <span class="menu-text">{{menu.name}}</span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-4">
                            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-right"></i>
                        </div>
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
```

seed-app.ts:

```
export class SeedApp implements OnInit {
private service:LogService;
private passwordResult = '';
private old_psd:string;
private psd:string;
private new_psd:string;
private menus = [
    {name: 'real_time_results', address:['/static/real_time_results']},
    {name: 'deployment', address: ['/static/deployment']},
    {name: 'setting', address: ['/static/setting']},
];
```

Comment: If you can provide a proper reproduction (Plunker) than create a bug report.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem has been solved,I have error imported 'es6/shim';